# Passing jQuery into the Wordpress media uploader

Tags: jquery, media, media-modal

In a Wordpress plugin that I am working on, I am using the built-in Wordpress media uploader function ( wp.media ) to add photos. I am using the `selection` option to pre-select images in the media library once the modal opens. I thought it would be a cool idea to attach a new CSS class to these items and style them differently from other new images the user selects.

I am running into an issue with passing jQuery into the modal and I cannot seem to get the events right. The problem is that the images in the media uploader are dynamically generated once the modal is opened. I have tried adding my script to the `on` event (when the modal is opened), but this seems to be too early. Adding them to the `select` or `close` events is obviously too late.

The goal is to have a custom CSS class added to all the images that are pre-selected once the modal opens. Does anyone have any experience with passing jQuery into the media uploader modal?

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
//Image Uploader function                  
odp_slideshowImageUpload = {

    // Call this from the upload button to initiate the upload frame.
    uploader : function() {
        var frame = wp.media({
            title : 'Choose or Upload an Image(s)',
            multiple : true,
            library : { type : 'image' }, //only can upload images
            button : { text : 'Insert Image(s)' }
        });

        frame.on( 'open', function() {
            var selection = frame.state().get('selection');

            // Get the id of all the images already in the slideshow
            var ids = $( '#odp_slider_container li[id]' ).map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
            // When our modal opens, make all of the images "selected"
            ids.forEach( function(id) {
                attachment = wp.media.attachment(id);
                attachment.fetch();
                selection.add( attachment ? [ attachment ] : [] );
            });


            $('.media-modal-content li.selected').addClass('testing'); //does not work

        });

        // Handle results from media manager
        frame.on( 'select', function() {
            var selection = frame.state().get( 'selection' );
            selection.map( function( attachment ) {
                attachment = attachment.toJSON();
                $( '#odp_slider_container' ).append( function() {
                    var output = '';

                    output += '<li id="' + attachment.id + '" class="odp-slideshow-item" >';
                    output += '<div class="slide-container"><image  src="' + attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url + '" alt="' + attachment.alt + '" /></div>';
                    output += '<input type="text" class="slide-id odp-force-hidden" name="slide_id[]" value="' + attachment.id + '" />';
                    output += '<input type="text" class="slide-image odp-force-hidden" name="slide_image[]" value="' + attachment.url + '" />';
                    output += '<input type="text" class="slide-title odp-force-hidden" name="slide_title[]" value="' + attachment.title + '" />';
                    output += '<input type="text" class="slide-alt odp-force-hidden" name="slide_alt[]" value="' + attachment.alt + '" />';
                    output += '<input type="text" class="slide-caption odp-force-hidden" name="slide_caption[]" value="' + attachment.caption + '" />';
                    output += '<div class="details-container"><a class="details" href="#">Details</a><a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></div>';
                    output += '</li>';

                    return output;
                });
            });
        });

        frame.open();
        return false;

    },

};
```

I understand this is a complicated question, so let me know if I could be more clear in certain areas.

Comment: Have you tried using the explicit "jQuery" instead of the shortened "$"? Just thinking that it might be a noConflict issue unless you explicitly defined $ somewhere.

Comment: Hi @Otto thanks for the suggestion, but yes, I wrap the whole thing in a no-conflict wrapper: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`. This is a tricky one I think. I have done quite a bit of "Googling" on the topic with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention the media uploader dynamically renders the images "on demand" and there doesn't seem to be an event one can target to add the class. A gross way to do it is to override the `wp.media.view.Attachment.Library.className` attribute (before the frame is created) to return the extra class if the model id is in the initial selection. It means moving the ids select outside the open, eg

```
//Image Uploader function                  
odp_slideshowImageUpload = {

    // Call this from the upload button to initiate the upload frame.
    uploader : function() {
        // Get the id of all the images already in the slideshow
        var ids = $( '#odp_slider_container li[id]' ).map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
        wp.media.view.Attachment.Library = wp.media.view.Attachment.Library.extend({
            className: function () { return $.inArray(this.model.get('id').toString(), ids ) !== -1 ? 'attachment testing' : 'attachment'; }
        });
        var frame = wp.media({
            // etc
```

Comment: Thanks bonger. I agree, not the prettiest solution, but it works. This was a lot more complicated than I thought it would be. I expected there to be a built in event that I could target, but oh well...